# How to access Azure Service Bus using Function App identity

Tags: python, azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity

I am following the steps listed here, but for python code:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial-2

Objective is to create a simple (hello world) function app which is triggered by Azure Service Bus message queue using identity-based connection. Function app works fine when ASB is reference via connection string, but gives this error when trying to connect via managed service identity of function app (used the specific configuration pattern __fullyQualifiedNamespace). MSI has been granted Role (Azure Service Bus Data Receiver) on ASB.

`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace' is missing or empty.`

**Function code** (autogenerated)

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus queue trigger processed message: %s',
                 msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

**function.json** (connection value modified based on ms docs)

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "erpdemoqueue",
      "connection": "ServiceBusConnection"
    }
  ]
}
```

**host.json** (version modified based on ms docs)

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

[image: architecture]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use a managed identity, you'll need to add a setting that identifies the fully qualified namespace of your Service Bus instance.

For example, in your `local.settings.json` file for local development:

```json
{
  "Values": {
    "<connection_name>__fullyQualifiedNamespace": "<service_bus_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net"
  }
}
```

Or in the [application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings) for your function when deployed to Azure:

```
<connection_name>__fullyQualifiedNamespace=<service_bus_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net
```

This is mentioned only briefly in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com//azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial-2#connect-to-service-bus-in-your-function-app) that you linked.  The `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` documentation does covers this a bit better in the [Managed identity authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/overview/azure/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus-readme#managed-identity-authentication) section.

Comment: Jesse, I had already put the variable in configuration according the naming convention mentioned by you (and the ms docs). (I mentioned it in the diagram) Still no success. Any thing else I could be missing?

Comment: The only thing that occurs to me is that an older version of the extensions package is in use.   According to the [config](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-extension-bundles/blob/v3.x/src/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/extensions.json#L32) v5+ of the Service Bus extension is referenced, but the error message that you're seeing is not [the one that I'd expect](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/src/Config/ServiceBusClientFactory.cs#L80).  That may just be coming from the host.

Comment: You may want to try removing the bundle and adding an explicit reference to the latest Service Bus extension via `func extensions install --package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus --version 5.2.0`   _([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register))_

Comment: Thank you Jesse. Explicitly installing the extension fixed it. I had to remove the existing extension bundle from host.json first.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me, but I'm trying to achieve the same on an old school .net framework WebJob. Any special clues that you can add to the mix here? I think I've tried every permutation of this connection string.

Comment: @The Senator:  this question is specific to the Functions infrastructure which manages the clients for you.   It won't work for a WebJob where you're managing clients yourself.   I'd suggest reading through the "Identity and Shared Access Credentials" sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample06_IdentityAndSharedAccessCredentials.md

Comment: @JesseSquire thanks, it was previously working fine on an older library in .net framework. But that was back in the days of the connection string including the ;Authentication=Managed Identity; and [ServiceBusTrigger] attributes. But in the new libraries I get caught between this being malformed, and the __fullyQualifiedNamespace not being seen by my app. Painful.