# How to use a service principal in azure function (python) to listen to azure service bus

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-service-principal

I have an azure function written in python which is listening to an azure service bus. The authentication is done by an azure service bus connection string. I want to change the authentication to a service principal. How can I implement this in my azure function?

Below is my function.json file. I expect that there are other values possible for the "connection" parameter.

```
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "queue_name",
      "connection": "ASB_CONNECTION_STR"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access Azure Service Bus using Function App identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71142868/how-to-access-azure-service-bus-using-function-app-identity)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested  by [User Jesse Squire - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159548/jesse-squire), use this connection parameter in your `local.settings.json` :

```
{
"Values": {
"<connection_name>__fullyQualifiedNamespace": "<service_bus_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net"
}
}
```

Or in the [application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings) for your function when deployed to Azure:

```
<connection_name>__fullyQualifiedNamespace=<service_bus_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net
```

References: [Use identity-based connections with Azure Functions triggers and bindings | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial-2#connect-to-service-bus-in-your-function-app) and [Azure WebJobs Service Bus client library for .NET - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus-readme#managed-identity-authentication)